# Best way to convert SlateJs to pdf

Tags: reactjs, text-editor, jspdf, slatejs, slate

I don't know if is the best way, but i trying to converte slate js  to pdf using jspdf.
o realized that it is not easy. convert slate js 'Value' to jspdf can be very complicate.
someone know if there is some other way to converte slate js to pdf, a pluguin, function or module thant can help me.

thanks

Comment: Currently, I am using `pagedjs`. I haven't run into any complications till now. You can go through it doc. It's quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a solution to convert the editor div to pdf with jspdf.html(...)